# How to make a webpage with multiple pages appear as one continuous page

Tags: web, scroll

Hi I am frequenter of ilfehacker.com.au and many other sites who constantly put content I want on ten pages instead of one easy to read long page.

Is there any way to tell the site to show me all the pages one after the other in one continuous long page?

I was thinking a greesemonkey script maybe or some addon?

Many Thanks, Josh.

Answer (score 0):

No, because there can only be 1 page per tab. You can write a firefox addon script that will detect whether you have scrolled to the bottom and than focus the browser on the the next tab and  vice versa.